# A case in which the integral equals 0 implies that the function is zero

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $x$,$y$ be real-valued functions defined and continuous on the closed interval $[a,b]$. Then,
$\int_{a}^{b} |x(t)-y(t)| \,dx = 0$ implies $|x(t)-y(t)| = 0$ for every $t \in [a,b]$. I know that continuity is a neccesary condition and I tried to used it with the definition of the Riemann integral (Rosenlicht, introduction to Analysis, chapter VI), but I didn't see a path.

Could you give me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb R$ continuous and positive s.t. $$\int_0^1f=0.$$

Suppose $f\neq 0$. Therefore, since $f$ is continuous, there $t\in (0,1)$ s.t. $f(t)\neq 0$. By continuity of $f$, there is $\delta >0$ s.t. $(t-\delta ,t+\delta )\subset (0,1)$ and $f(s)\geq \frac{f(t)}{2}$ for all $s\in (t-\delta ,t+\delta ).$ Then $$\int_0^1f(s)\,\mathrm d s\geq \int_{t-\delta }^{t+\delta }f(s)\,\mathrm d s\geq f(t)\delta >0,$$
which is a contradiction with $\int_0^1 f=0$.